# Передача Blob на сервер и обратно на клиент

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, streaming, webrtc

Записываю видео с вебкамеры с помощью MediaRecorder 100мс отрезками способом описанным [здесь](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/getusermedia/record/js/main.js). Когда кусок готов, я отправляю его с помощью socket.io на сервер (на сервере node.js 6.3.0). Сервер записывает этот кусок в базу и отдает его по сокету всем остальным. Точно известно, что на сервер приходят правильные данные, я могу сохранить любой кусок и запустить видео (потом их склеиваю и получаю запись). Проблема в том, что по возвращению данных обратно на клиент, они получаются невалидными. В чем может быть проблема?

Код отправки на сервер:

```
// Инициализирую бинарный режим
socket = io();
socket.binaryType = 'blob';

// Делаю Blob и отсылаю его
var blob = new Blob([event.data], {type: 'video/webm'});
socket.emit('message', blob);
```

Код отправки на клиент:

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('broadcast', message);
}
```

На клиенте обрабатываю так:

```
socket.on('broadcast', function(data) {
    window.videoBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'video/webm'});
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    video.load();

    // Получаю такую ошибку:
    // Не удалось декодировать медиаресурс blob:http://localhost:4000/85ebba31-2993-4171-a11f-9798e4633e1c.
}
```

Для ясности покажу, что передается друг другу:

```
// От клиента на сервер:
Blob {size: 137305, type: "video/webm"}
// Что получает сервер от клиента:
<Buffer 41 81 81 04 38 80 fb 83 7b 7f 9a 9d 65 31 e2 75 2a d7 94 94 af c8 63 41 ab 95 83 ae 79 37 d2 00 7b d8 66 4a cc 2b c5 01 f4 7a 3c 14 69 4e e5 95 d1 58 ... > // aka ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 137305 }
// Что получает клиент от сервера:
ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 137305 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var blob = new Blob([event.data], {type: 'video/webm'});
socket.emit('message', blob);  - ты уже блоб создал 

socket.on('broadcast', function(data) {
window.videoBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'video/webm'}); - тут зачем второй раз создавать когда у тебя уе создан при отправке  ?
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
video.load();
```

Comment: Отформатируйте пожалуйста код воспользовавшись кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/977605/edit).